# JMeter vs ReadyAPI SOAP API Performance Testing

Tags: soap, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Scenario: Read data from a CSV file with unknown number of records. Use the data to create Soap XML MSg and Post Method. Continue to do this until all the records have been read.

Problem: I used ReadyAPI to perform these actions and was able to achieve the intended TPS at server with whatever i have provided in VU's option. Tried with 150 vu's and observed constant load of 150 requests at the server. But when i try to do the same in JMeter, i was not able to achieve more than 70 TPS and the load isn't evenly distributed as well no matter how many threads i use. I am using a Thread Group, CSV DataSet Config, UserDefined Parameters to create unique request ID and JSR223 PreProcessor with Groovy Script as a child of HTTPRequest to remove empty xml tags.

Read some posts where it was mentioned that JMeter throughput will be stagnant based on servers response capability. But it's not in my case since i can generate 150TPS with ReadyAPI. Annual Licensing costs and Renewal costs associated with ReadyAPI is the Reason that i am looking for solution with JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the server need to be able to respond fast enough, **JMeter must be able to send requests fast enough as well**.

Default JMeter configuration is suitable for tests development and debugging and creating some load (rather limited though), you need to properly tune your JMeter instance in order to fully utilize your machine resources so make sure to follow:

- [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

If your single machine is not powerful enough to conduct the required load it's possible to run JMeter in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) using as many load generators as needed in order to create the necessary number of virtual users/requests per second